# Rotating a child object relative to its parent

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I'm trying to make a camera system that rotates around a target based on mouse movement. So far I achieved this by creating a sphere mesh centered on the target and attaching a camera to it, placing it on its surface. So by rotating the sphere I also rotate the camera. So far so good.

I implemented a system to make the camera move closer if something is blocking the view, I do so by making a spherecast between the center of the sphere and the camera position, and then changing the scale of the sphere to the distance between the sphere center and the spherecast hit position. Probably not the best system, but it seems to work.

The problem I'm facing is that when the target is on the ground it's impossible to make the camera look up, as doing so will make it get closer and closer to the target, until it blocks the entire screen.

To solve that I'm trying to rotate the camera instead of the sphere when rotation along the Z axis is below a certain amount (right now I'm using -0.3). This way the camera would stay in the same place, but look upwards, without the target getting in the way. However when I do this, the camera rotates in a completely different way than the one I want, despite me using pretty much the same code I use for the sphere; I also rotated the camera with similar code in another project, and it also worked, leading me to thing that the issue here might be the fact that the camera is a child object of the sphere, tough I might be wrong.

Here is the script I use for everything I just described

```cs
public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 targetOffset;

    private Transform radius;
    [SerializeField] float _defaultRadius;
    private float _radius;
    [SerializeField] float unclipDistance;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask obstacleMask;

    [SerializeField] private float _mouseSensitivity;

    private float _rotationX, _rotationY;

    private Vector3 _currentRotation;

    [SerializeField] private float _cameraRotationX;
    private Vector3 _currentCameraRotation;

    [SerializeField] private Vector2 minRotation;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 maxRotation;

    private Vector3 _smoothVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    [SerializeField] private float _smoothTime;

    void Start()
    {
        radius = transform.parent.transform;
        radius.localScale = new Vector3(_defaultRadius *2, _defaultRadius *2, _defaultRadius *2);
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        radius.position = target.position + targetOffset;

        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _mouseSensitivity;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _mouseSensitivity;

        _rotationY += mouseX;
        _rotationX -= mouseY;

        if (_rotationX < minRotation.x)
            touchingGroundMode(mouseY);
        else return;
        
        _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minRotation.x, maxRotation.x);

        Vector3 nextRotation = new Vector3(_currentRotation.x, _rotationY, _rotationX);

        _currentRotation = Vector3.SmoothDamp(_currentRotation, nextRotation, ref _smoothVelocity, _smoothTime);
        radius.localEulerAngles = _currentRotation;

        checKCollision();
    }

    void checKCollision()
    {
        Vector3 rayDirection = (transform.position - radius.position).normalized;
        Vector3 hypotheticalPos = rayDirection * _defaultRadius;

        Ray ray = new Ray(radius.position, rayDirection * _defaultRadius);
        Debug.DrawRay(radius.position, rayDirection * _defaultRadius, Color.green);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, 0.5f, out hit, Vector3.Distance(hypotheticalPos, radius.position), obstacleMask))
        {
            _radius = Vector3.Distance(hit.point, radius.position) - unclipDistance;
        }
        else _radius = _defaultRadius;

        radius.localScale = new Vector3(_radius * 2, _radius * 2, _radius * 2);
    }

    void touchingGroundMode(float mouseY)
    {
        float leftoverMouseY = mouseY;

        _cameraRotationX -= leftoverMouseY;

        Vector3 nextRotation = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, transform.localEulerAngles.y, _cameraRotationX);
        _currentCameraRotation = Vector3.SmoothDamp(_currentCameraRotation, nextRotation, ref _smoothVelocity, _smoothTime);
        transform.localEulerAngles = _currentCameraRotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not the first to try this, it's quite common :) There are many solutions: https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+camera+orbit+script

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use this code to make what you want.

```
 public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 targetOffset;

    private Transform radius;
    [SerializeField] float _defaultRadius;
    private float _radius;
    [SerializeField] float unclipDistance;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask obstacleMask;

    [SerializeField] private float _mouseSensitivity;

    private float _rotationX, _rotationY;

    private Vector3 _currentRotation;

    [SerializeField] private Camera camera;

    [SerializeField] private Vector2 minRotation;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 maxRotation;

    private Vector3 _smoothVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    [SerializeField] private float _smoothTime;

    void Start()
    {
        radius = transform.parent.transform;
        radius.localScale = new Vector3(_defaultRadius *2, _defaultRadius *2, _defaultRadius *2);
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        radius.position = target.position + targetOffset;

        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _mouseSensitivity;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _mouseSensitivity;

        _rotationY += mouseX;
        _rotationX -= mouseY;

        if (_rotationX < minRotation.x)
            touchingGroundMode(mouseY);
        else return;
        
        _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minRotation.x, maxRotation.x);

        Vector3 nextRotation = new Vector3(_currentRotation.x, _rotationY, _rotationX);

        _currentRotation = Vector3.SmoothDamp(_currentRotation, nextRotation, ref _smoothVelocity, _smoothTime);

        // Decouple the camera from the sphere
        camera.transform.rotation = _currentRotation;
    }

    void checKCollision()
    {
        Vector3 rayDirection = (transform.position - radius.position).normalized;
        Vector3 hypotheticalPos = rayDirection * _defaultRadius;

        Ray ray = new Ray(radius.position, rayDirection * _defaultRadius);
        Debug.DrawRay(radius.position, rayDirection * _defaultRadius, Color.green);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, 0.5f, out hit, Vector3.Distance(hypotheticalPos, radius.position), obstacleMask))
        {
            _radius = Vector3.Distance(hit.point, radius.position) - unclipDistance;
        }
        else _radius = _defaultRadius;

        radius.localScale = new Vector3(_radius * 2, _radius * 2, _radius * 2);
    }

    void touchingGroundMode(float mouseY)
    {
        float leftoverMouseY = mouseY;

        camera.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, leftoverMouseY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This still doesn't work quite how I want it to, but it's much much closer. Starting from this I should (hopefully) be able to fix the rest of the code,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).